# Wrap food in cylinder shape and put in the fridge

Tags: meat

What the technique call?, if you would wrap food in a cylinder shape and put in the fridge to let it set. I see Chef flat the meat and added flat shrimp on top, then roll it in cling wrap, put it in the fridge and it come out like sausage. Not only protein item but also I see Chef do it with eggplant and its puree. 
I am wondering what the technique is call and how it work exactly.

Answer (score 9):

This is called a **roulade**. It is when a protein or vegetable is rolled, typically in plastic, very tightly.  It is sometimes also tied. The roulade, can be poached or cooked sous vide in the wrapping, if it is to be a hot preparation.  It can also be refrigerated for cold preparations.  The cooking, or refrigeration, help keep the roll in tact when slicing for service.  A modernist technique for maintaining the roll might be to use transglutaminase (otherwise known as "meat glue").